# visual basic & sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, deployment, visual-studio-2012, web-parts

I am new to SharePoint.

My head in the office told me that if you want to learn SharePoint, you have to learn ASP.Net first because we need to add webparts to the portal.

I installed visual studio ultimate 2012 to start learning ASP.NET. I found that I can use c# or VB.NET in programming ASP.NET. I actually have experience in VB for building windows applications but do not know about c#.

Note: I am working on windows 7 professional edition 64 bit. we are using SharePoint 2010.

My questions are:

Can I use VB to program webparts in SharePoint?

Does programming with vb for windows application is similar to programming for SharePoint?

I can now access the SharePoint portal throw the browser. Should I install SharePoint on my computer to program webparts for SharePoint by visual studio?

Do you know any useful article could help me in learning programming for SharePoint?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use VB to program webparts in SharePoint? Does programming with vb for windows application is similar to programming for SharePoint?

If you meant VB.NET you can definitely use it. But the programming model is totally different from traditional Windows appplications, especially VB6 for that matter.

> Should I install SharePoint on my computer to program webparts for SharePoint by visual studio?

As of SharePoint 2010, yes.

> Do you know any useful article could help me in learning programming for SharePoint?

You can start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620703

Comment: Thank you so much, you have  answered my critical questions.

You said that programing in vb for sharepoint is different from programming  traditional Windows applications. So I have to learn something new. Do you advise me to learn  c# or vb ?
 
And do you advise me to install sharepoint 2010 on my device or I have to use virtual machine ?

Comment: Best to use a VM as SP installs a bunch of stuff. Re: C# vs VB for SharePoint, I hate to choose sides but the sad reality is more samples are in C#. This won't be an issue if you really on Microsoft sites though like: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/